# Помогите правильно разместить блок

Tags: html, css

Помогите разместить блок(content) под меню, а то я голову уже сломал. И все ни как не получается.

Код [тут](https://codepen.io/art_code/pen/BayQYOM?editors=1100) HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">О Нас</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
                    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Вакансии</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
                    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Соглашение</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navEnter"><a href="#"><span>Войти</span></a></li>
                    <li class="navReg"><a href="#"><span>Зарегестрироватся</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>This one is the sub-section or widget title</h1>
        <h2>Next one is the item title inside widgets</h2>
        <h3>This is a label or CTA text</h3>
        <p>This is the body text which is used for most of the design, like paragraphs, lists, etc.</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {


margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 100px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header .logo {
  color: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.5);
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}
header nav {
  float: right;
}
header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
header nav ul li.sub-menu:before {
  content: "";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.5);
  right: 2px;
}
header nav ul li.active.sub-menu:before {
  content: "";
}
header nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.05);
  display: none;
}
header nav ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
header nav ul li a {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.5);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
header nav ul li a:hover, header nav ul li a.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #BC9CFF;
}

.navEnter span {
  border: 2px solid #BC9CFF;
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  color: #BC9CFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navEnter span:hover, .navEnter span.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #BC9CFF;
}
.navEnter a:hover, .navEnter a.active {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}

.navReg span {
  border: 2px solid #BC9CFF;
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #BC9CFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navReg span:hover, .navReg span.active {
  color: #BC9CFF;
  background: #fff;
}
.navReg a:hover, .navReg a.active {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}

header nav ul li.active ul {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-toggle {
  color: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.5);
  float: right;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  header {
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  header nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc( 100vh - 50px );
    top: 50px;
    left: -100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  header nav.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  header nav ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  header nav ul a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  header nav ul li.sub-menu:before {
    right: 10px;
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }

  header nav ul li.active ul {
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.05);
  }

  header nav ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: не сомвсем пойму зачем Вам `position: absolute;` для `header`, ну да ладно, для `content` просто добавьте отступ сверху равное высоте `header`, в Вашем случае `50px;`

Answer (score 1):

Убрал абсолютное позиционирование, блок контента опустил и выравнял за счёт `flex`-свойств.

[Смотреть изменения](https://codepen.io/drsg/pen/bGNBMzv?editors=1100)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('active')
  })
  $('ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 100px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header .logo {
  color: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.5);
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

header nav ul li.sub-menu:before {
  content: "";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.5);
  right: 2px;
}

header nav ul li.active.sub-menu:before {
  content: "";
}

header nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.05);
  display: none;
}

header nav ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

header nav ul li a {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.5);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

header nav ul li a:hover,
header nav ul li a.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #BC9CFF;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.content h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.content h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.content h3 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.content p {
  margin: 0;
}

.navEnter span {
  border: 2px solid #BC9CFF;
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  color: #BC9CFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navEnter span:hover,
.navEnter span.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #BC9CFF;
}

.navEnter a:hover,
.navEnter a.active {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}

.navReg span {
  border: 2px solid #BC9CFF;
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #BC9CFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navReg span:hover,
.navReg span.active {
  color: #BC9CFF;
  background: #fff;
}

.navReg a:hover,
.navReg a.active {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}

header nav ul li.active ul {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-toggle {
  color: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.5);
  float: right;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  header {
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  header nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc( 100vh - 50px);
    top: 50px;
    left: -100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  header nav.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  header nav ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  header nav ul a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  header nav ul li.sub-menu:before {
    right: 10px;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  header nav ul li.active ul {
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(31, 32, 65, 0.05);
  }
  header nav ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">О Нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Вакансии</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Соглашение</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="navEnter"><a href="#"><span>Войти</span></a></li>
        <li class="navReg"><a href="#"><span>Зарегистрироваться</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>This one is the sub-section or widget title</h1>
  <h2>Next one is the item title inside widgets</h2>
  <h3>This is a label or CTA text</h3>
  <p>This is the body text which is used for most of the design, like paragraphs, lists, etc.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть еще проблема при срабатывании выпадающего меню оно заезжает под DIV с классом content. Пробовал и позиционирование и z-index и не в какую.